# What will hapeen if we remove air from a pipe

Tags: gravity, home-experiment

At first i did not know if this relate to engineering or physics but i think it mostly relate for physics so i posted here.

My question is what would happen if we have a pipe set vertically and have some water, and then we removed the air from that pipe, after that we opened the down side which the water will be there, does the water will go down, or the pipe will try to get air and push the water up?

**Update:**
Please see the below image for what i mean.

And as some of you commented that the width of the pipe will affect the behavior, how can i measure what width could push the water up.

Sorry i am not very good at physics, but i am looking for which topic should i read to continue research on this thing.

I need to know at first is it possible that the water will go up when we open the bottom side, and what topics i should research on to calculate how much the water be pushed up and a pipe width with an amount of water on a specific temperature.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Sooo not clear.

Comment: Yeah, you need to clarify the situation. Is the pipe open at one end? Both ends?

Comment: Also, are we assuming capillary action is not in the mix? Not pipette size, relatively larger pipe.

Comment: Please clarify with a diagram.

Comment: I have added an image that should show what i exactly mean

Comment: That is not how you spell vacuum and the state in that diagram is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you start with a pipe closed at both ends and evacuated with the bottom end immersed in a pool of water.  A valve at the bottom is then opened and you wonder what happens.  The air pressure on the water outside the pipe will force water into the pipe.  The water will rise either until it hits the top of the pipe or until the water column exerts an equal pressure to the atmosphere, which happens at about 33 feet (10 meters).  IF the water does not fill the pipe, water will evaporate until the pressure in the volume above the water is at the vapor pressure of water at the water temperature.  At $20$C this is $0.023$ atm.  This reduces the water column height by about $23$ cm.  The principle is the same for a [mercury barometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer#Mercury_barometers), except that the higher density of mercury means it only rises about 30 inches (760 mm).

Comment: Note that depending on the temperature, the void above the water will be filled with water vapor up to the partial pressure at that temperature. This means the height of the liquid column will be less than 10 m as the differential pressure supporting the column will be less than 1 atm.

Comment: @Floris:  that is true.  At 20C it is $0.023$ atm, so the column height will be reduced by about $23$ cm

Comment: Right - not insignificant. May I suggest you add it to your answer? You already have my upvote...

Comment: Thanks! it was not what i really asked for, but it gaves me some ideas, its really helping and clarified, just if you could support me with which topic i should research on to calculate the what width of pipe i need to push an amount of water in a specific temperature

Comment: I gave you the height of the water in the pipe.  To get the volume you just multiply by the area.  The temperature only changes the vapor pressure.  Are you thinking about flow rate instead of the volume that flows?

Answer (score 0):

Ross answers assumeing the pipe is empty but sitting in water: I assume you have a pipe half full of water and the upper half is vacuum.

When the bottom of the pipe is opened, the water will try to fall down while the air outside pushes up on it. The two will push past each other and you'll end up with bubbles rising through the water while the water pours out of the bottom turbulently.

If the pipe is small enough in diameter, the water surface tension will hold the lower surface together and the entire column will be forced up into the top half of the pipe.

Comment: Thanks!
Could you please advise which topic should i read to have the ability to determine what is the width of the pipe should i have to push an amount of water.